# How to use query parameters in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have two user groups in a DB. I want to query the DB to show a checkboxGroup in a Shiny app, with only one of the groups, depending on a URL query parameter.

For example, with a URL query parameters like this:

http://127.0.0.1:4014/?groupId=1

ideally, I would like to get that groupId value and use it to filter the user group:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(con, paste('SELECT user_id, user_name
        FROM   info i , enrolment e 
        WHERE  i.user_id = e.fk_user_id 
        AND    e.fk_group_id = ', groupId))
dataf <- dbFetch(res)
userlist <- as.list(setNames(dataf$user_id, dataf$user_name))
```

and then show the content of that userlist within Shiny, as a checkboxGroup, like so:

```
ui <- fluidPage( column(3, checkboxGroupInput("users", 
                                label = h3("User Names"), 
                                choices = userlist)))
```

Is it possible to pass such URL query parameters -as groupId in my example- to a Shiny app? (My code is working OK if I hard-code the groupId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html

Here's what you're looking for:

```
groupId <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
```

Just remember to add

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session)
```

It can look something like this at the end of the day:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  h3("groupId"),
  verbatimTextOutput("queryText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$queryText <- renderText({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    paste(query, sep = "", collapse=", ")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Looking at your gist, you need to put your database objects/variables in the server part.

```
server(function(input, output, session) {
  source("keys.R")
  con <- dbConnect( MySQL(), user=login, password=pass, db=database, host=host)
```

Next, still in the server part, I would put, in either a observer or reactive expression, your dbGetQuery combined with the groupId parameter, and store the output.

This way you can apply that output to a checkboxGroupInput in the UI.

Comment: If I understood correctly, session variable is only available in the server part, using a reactive expression or an observer. I want to have access the groupId variable before the UI part is shown (I want to display the checkboxGroupInput values according to the groupId value). I have tried this : https://gist.github.com/juananpe/526d56f79e4606df4200 without success (in the sql query before the UI, groupId always takes the default value, 1)

Comment: ".. in the server part, I would put, in either a observer or reactive expression, your dbGetQuery". That did the trick. I was incorrectly trying to use dbGetQuery in the UI part. Thanks!